# How to create border that wraps iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this iframe:

```
<div onmousedown="alert()">
    <iframe id="PropertyCtrl" name="PropertyCtrl"  frameborder="0" style="border:thick solid #0000FF; cursor:w-resize;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I need to create border that wraps the iframe, when I navigate on the border and make click `onmousedown` event have to be fired.

How can I create border with  `onmousedown` event?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean and what you've tried? In particular, *"How can I create border with  onmousedown event?"* doesn't seem to fit in with the rest of your question.

Comment: If the iframe fills that element the event will always occur inside the frame window. If that iframe is cross domain you won't be able to access the event

Comment: ^^ what charlietfl said. If you want to handle this cross-origin, you'll need to overlay a transparent iframe over the cross-origin one and use a higher z-index on it. ***If*** that's what your question is, it's not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a border around that iframe by just putting a border on the `div`:

```
<div class="frame-border" ...>
   <iframe ... />
</div>
```

and then with the CSS:

```
.frame-border {
    border: thick solid #0000FF; /* Or whatever */
}
```

Or if you prefer inline styling:

```
<div style="border: thick solid #0000FF" ...>
   <iframe ... />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code:

```js
function borderShow()
{
 document.getElementById('PropertyCtrl').style = 'border:thick solid #00FFFF;';
}
```

```html
<div onmousedown="borderShow()">
    <iframe id="PropertyCtrl" name="PropertyCtrl"  frameborder="0" style="border:thick solid #0000FF; cursor:w-resize;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: note if frame fills container event will always be inside the frame window and won't register on the div...even if it doesn't fill it, whenever cursor is over frame the event defintiely won't register on div

Answer (score 1):

- Changed the function so it can be reused.
- It toggles between `.off` and `.on` classes.
- The methods `classList.add/remove` are used to manipulate the classes.
- Changed the mousedown event into the universally generic click.

#### SNIPPET

```js
function outlineTarget(tgt) {
  var target = document.querySelector(tgt);
  if (target.classList.contains('off')) {
    target.classList.add('on');
    target.classList.remove('off');
  } else {
    target.classList.add('off');
    target.classList.remove('on');
  }
}
```

```css
#ctrl.off {
  border: 0 solid #0000FF;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#ctrl.on {
  border: 10px ridge #0000FF;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="outlineTarget('#ctrl')">
  <iframe id="ctrl" name="ctrl" class='off' src="http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <p>Click anywhere on this text or to the right of iframe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why no mention of the event on iframe? Just ignoring it? Suppose it's not cross domain?

Comment: I was going to put an overlay over everything, but the OP isn't completely clear as to the conditions that pertain to his/her situation.

Comment: Wouldn't make sense if the OP wants to navigate in frame otherwise why would they be wanting mouse event?...but if frame is on same domain the events can be captured. You bought into answering this one. Good luck

Comment: "How can I create border with  onmousedown event?" That just tells me OP desires a border when clicked. It could be for presentation, navigation,  a school assignment, etc. There are many times that what an OP considers logical and sound does not coincide with what I consider sane and logical. There are times when I am on the wrong path and the most obvious of solutions eludes me. Perhaps this is one of those times. When I wake up, I might have an epiphany till then, good night or morning to you, sir.

Comment: yup ...amen to that. Not trying to be a hard ass...enjoy